# image from database phpmyadmin

Tags: php

I have a little problem I try to display a url image that there is in my phpmyadmin database, but nothing is displayed. I am trying to display an image from my database. I put you my code and my line of the database. Thank you in advance for your help ![image]

see if I made a mistake in the code, or if I used the wrong path

the URL of my image is called "img_l" in my database and it is in a category called "liste"

Voici mon code :

```
<?php
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animebd;chaset=utf8','root','');
    $req = $bdd->query('SELECT img_l,nomL FROM liste');
    while($donnees = $req->fetch()){
        echo('<img style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius;:500px;" img_l = "' . $donnees['img_l'] . '"/><br/>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please share more details. What exactly is not working? Also, please share the code involved **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem.

Comment: "nothing is displayed" - what does that mean? Did you check the generated markup?

Comment: Check if  $req has data from database or not you can use var_dump($req);

Comment: What is in `img_l` stored? The image itself or filename or a path to a file?

Comment: the $req to check sql query result?!

Answer (score 1):

In image tag, you don't have src attribute. You must add it and concatenate your data from db with images directory.

```php
$path = './public/images/' . $donnees['img_l'];
```

of course my answer is valid only if `$donnees['img_l']` is the filename with extension (mycar.jpg)